# Print all values of array with a nested index in PHP without a loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array which has nested String that I want to output without a loop.

Here is the array:

```
$field_my_array[0]['string_term']->name = "First";
$field_my_array[1]['string_term']->name = "Second";
$field_my_array[2]['string_term']->name = "Third";
$field_my_array[3]['string_term']->name = "Forth";
$field_my_array[4]['string_term']->name = "Fifth";
```

I want to output this as

> First, Second, Third, Forth, Fifth

### This is what I tried (but it's in loop)

```
   for ($ctr = 0; $ctr < count($field_my_array); $ctr ++) {
        print $field_my_array[$ctr]['string_term']->name;
        if ($ctr < count($field_my_array) -1) {print ", ";} 
      }
```

Comment: Great! So what have you [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)?

Comment: Are you trying to play code golf?  A loop would be the most obvious way to do it, and the guy working on the code after you would probably appreciate it. That being said, is [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) what you’re looking for?

Comment: I've seen dozens of posts of the years with people insistent that they don't want to use a loop, is there some textbook out there that says "loops bad!" ?

Comment: Tried `array_map` ?

Comment: You will need a loop of some kind if the number of elements ever changes. If it doesn't just echo each element in turn. Also, `array_map` is surely still a loop under the hood...

Answer (score 2):

I'd be inclined to break this down into two parts:

1. Convert the array into a simplified version that just contains the values you want to concatenate. For that, you can use `array_map()` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).
2. Join the elements of the array without an extra comma on the end. The perfect use case for `implode()` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Example:

```
echo implode(', ', array_map(function($item) {
    return $item['string_term']->name;
}, $field_my_array));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you're trying to achieve. If you don't want to loop, then you have to manually write like this:

```
echo $field_my_array[0]['string_term']->name;
echo ", ";
echo $field_my_array[1]['string_term']->name;
...
```

and so on. Looping is a fundamental programming construct that allows us to automate with a simple count.

```
for ($ctr = 0; $ctr < count($field_my_array); $ctr ++) {
        print $field_my_array[$ctr]['string_term']->name;
        if ($ctr < count($field_my_array) -1) {print ", ";} 
      }
```

A better one would be this:

```
$field_my_array[0]['string_term']->name = "First";
$field_my_array[1]['string_term']->name = "Second";
$field_my_array[2]['string_term']->name = "Third";
$field_my_array[3]['string_term']->name = "Forth";
$field_my_array[4]['string_term']->name = "Fifth";

$names = array();

    for ($ctr = 0; $ctr < count($field_my_array); $ctr ++) {
                $names[] = $field_my_array[$ctr]['string_term']->name; 
              }
     // this creates a string with a comma between items from array         
     $full_text = implode(', ',$names);

     echo $full_text ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_merge_recursive` with `implode`

```
$c = array_merge_recursive(...$field_my_array);
echo implode(',', $c['string_term']['name']);
```

Live DEMO https://3v4l.org/GdhM5